# How to select weekly data and perform further calculations and then group them in r

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, cbind

I have the following data:

```
 Date          Price
 2-Jul-13      20
 3-Jul-13      22
 4-Jul-13      30
 5-Jul-13      18     
 8-Jul-13      12
 9-Jul-13      24
10-Jul-13      28
11-Jul-13      14
```

The output has to be:

```
  Date        Price   day_diff   week_diff
 2-Jul-13      20         0          4  
 3-Jul-13      22         2
 4-Jul-13      30         8
 5-Jul-13      18       -12
 8-Jul-13      12        -6
 9-Jul-13      24        12         -4  
10-Jul-13      28         4
11-Jul-13      14        -14 
12-Jul-13      18         4
15-Jul-13      12        -6
16-Jul-13      20         8         ....  
    ....
```

To calculate day_diff first value is taken as 0 and then 22-20 = 2 and so on. To calculate week_diff the next week starts from 9-Jul-13 so 24-20 = 4 similarly next week starts from 16-July-13 so 20-24 = -4 and so on...

Please help me with this.

Comment: Try `mutate(day_diff = Price - lag(Price))` using `library(dplyr)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide your data with `dput()` in future.

The data:

```
read.table(
  text = " Date        Price
2-Jul-13      20
3-Jul-13      22
4-Jul-13      30
5-Jul-13      18
8-Jul-13      12
9-Jul-13      24
10-Jul-13      28
11-Jul-13      14
12-Jul-13      18
15-Jul-13      12
16-Jul-13      20 ",
  header = T
) -> df
```

Solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(
    Date = dmy(Date),
    day_diff = Price - lag(Price),
    week_date = floor_date(Date, unit = 'week', week_start = 2),
    week_number = ifelse(Date == week_date, Price, 0),
    week_diff = lead(week_number, 5) - week_number
  ) %>%
  select(Date, Price, day_diff, week_diff)-> output_df
```

Output

```
> output_df
         Date Price day_diff week_diff
1  2013-07-02    20       NA         4
2  2013-07-03    22        2         0
3  2013-07-04    30        8         0
4  2013-07-05    18      -12         0
5  2013-07-08    12       -6         0
6  2013-07-09    24       12        -4
7  2013-07-10    28        4        NA
8  2013-07-11    14      -14        NA
9  2013-07-12    18        4        NA
10 2013-07-15    12       -6        NA
11 2013-07-16    20        8        NA
```

Comment: What if i had to do 24-20/20 for week_diff???Please suggest

Comment: @spradnya ```week_diff = (lead(week_number, 5) - week_number)/week_number```